# Meteor: How to detect if users authenticated

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my app I use `accounts-github`. Works perfect, but I have one problem.

In one of my templates I do

```
Template.bar.rendered = function () {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        // setup stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the user initially is not logged in this code is not executed (thats ok). But when the user authenticates this code is not executed again. So the question is how can I listen for this change inside a template (doesn't have to be in inside the `rendered` function!)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Deps.autorun`. (http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun)

Usually `Deps.autorun` would run for your whole Meteor app. If you want to make it so that it only runs per template you would need to create and stop it in the rendered and destroyed template callbacks

e.g

```
var loginRun;

Template.bar.rendered = function() {
    loginRun = Deps.autorun(function() {
        if(Meteor.user()) {
            //Stuff to run when logged in
        }
    });
}

Template.bar.destroyed = function() {
    loginRun.stop();
}
```

If you don't need it to run per template (need it to run just once for you app on any template, then you can use the `Deps.autorun` on its own, anywhere in your client side code.

`Meteor.user()` is reactive, it would ensure that the Deps.autorun callback runs again when it changes, so you could theoretically use it to do things when the user logs in or out.

Other alternatives is there is a package on atmosphere that provides login and logout hooks, though they basically would use the Deps.autorun like above to work anyway. See https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-event-hooks

Comment: Perfect. These solutions are more elegant than my hack.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for similar problem was to

1. Attach an event to template where the login happens
2. Re-render template if login is succesful so the `Template.bar.rendered` is called

E.g.

```
Template.bar.events({ 
   'click .loginButton' : function() {
    if( Meteor.call.Login( username, pw ) )
    {
        $('#bar').html( Meteor.render( Template.bar ));
        //jQuery is optional
    }
});
```

Comment: I think currently this should be refactored to use `Blaze.Render`